# SQL not grouping up lower case and upper case email addresses

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am doing a SQL Query where query is not grouping together upper case and lower case email address. Though sql is not case sensitive I don't understand why it is doing so.

```
SELECT
Customers.EmailAddress,
o.TotalOrders AS 'overall NumOrders',
o.TotalOrdered AS 'overall TotalOrdered',
o1.TotalOrders AS '2017 NumOrders',
o1.TotalOrdered AS '2017 TotalOrdered',
o2.TotalOrders AS '2016 NumOrders',
o2.TotalOrdered AS '2016 TotalOrdered'
FROM Customers 
JOIN Orders
ON Customers.Customerid=Orders.Customerid
FULL  JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.EmailAddress,
COUNT(Orders.OrderID) as TotalOrders,
(SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount)) as TotalOrdered
FROM
Customers  WITH (NOLOCK),Orders  WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
 Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
AND Orders.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled','Payment Declined')
AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2016 00:00' AND '11/30/2017 23:59'
GROUP BY
Customers.EmailAddress
 ) AS o ON o.EmailAddress = Customers.EmailAddress
FULL  JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT
Customers.EmailAddress,
COUNT(Orders.OrderID) as TotalOrders,
SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) as TotalOrdered
FROM
Orders  WITH (NOLOCK), Customers  WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
AND Orders.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled','Payment Declined')
AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2017 00:00' AND '11/30/2017 23:59'
GROUP BY
Customers.EmailAddress
) AS o1 ON o1.EmailAddress = Customers.EmailAddress
FULL JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT
Customers.EmailAddress,
COUNT(Orders.OrderID) as TotalOrders,
SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) as TotalOrdered
FROM
Orders  WITH (NOLOCK), Customers  WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
AND Orders.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled','Payment Declined')
AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2016 00:00' AND '12/31/2016 23:59'
GROUP BY
Customers.EmailAddress
) AS o2 ON o2.EmailAddress = Customers.EmailAddress
WHERE Orders.Orderdate BETWEEN '1/1/2016 00:00' AND '11/30/2017 23:59'
 AND  Orders.OrderStatus NOT IN('Cancelled','Payment Declined')
GROUP BY
Customers.EmailAddress,
o.TotalOrders ,
o.TotalOrdered ,
o1.TotalOrders ,
o1.TotalOrdered ,
o2.TotalOrders ,
o2.TotalOrdered ,
o3.TotalOrders , 
o3.TotalOrdered
```

where I am getting following results. 
Results showing :

```
EMAILADDRESS           overallnumorders totalorders 2017totalorder ...2016 totalor
    SMITHWORKS @ GMAIL.COM   3                $23.99           3             
    smithworks@gmail.com     1
```

I want to combine both of these email into one:
   emailaddress                  overallnumorders..........
   smithworks@gmail.com    4     ......................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 email addresses differ by more than just case (there are 2 spaces as well
`SMITHWORKS @ GMAIL.COM <> smithworks@gmail.com` and so they would be "distinct" and hence treated as 2 rows.

You could try `lower(Customers.EmailAddress)` in both the select and group by clauses. Also your existing query can be simplified by using "conditional aggregates" (put a case expression inside an aggregate function):

```
SELECT
      lower(Customers.EmailAddress)
    , COUNT(Orders.OrderID)   AS 'overall NumOrders'
    , SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount)  AS 'overall TotalOrdered'
    , COUNT(case when Orders.OrderDate >= '20170101' then Orders.OrderID       end) AS '2017 NumOrders'
    , SUM(  case when Orders.OrderDate >= '20170101' then Orders.PaymentAmount end) AS '2017 TotalOrdered'
    , COUNT(case when Orders.OrderDate <  '20170101' then Orders.OrderID       end) AS '2016 NumOrders'
    , SUM(  case when Orders.OrderDate <  '20170101' then Orders.PaymentAmount end) AS '2016 TotalOrdered'
    , o2.TotalOrders  AS '2016 NumOrders'
    , o2.TotalOrdered AS '2016 TotalOrdered'
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders ON Customers.Customerid = Orders.Customerid
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Payment Declined')
AND Orders.OrderDate >= '20160101' AND Orders.OrderDate < '20171201'
GROUP BY
      lower(Customers.EmailAddress)
```

Notes:

- In SQL Server the safest possible date literal is **NOT** in MM/dd/yyyy. **The safest** way to specify a date in T-SQL is **YYYYMMDD** (no seperators)
- `AND '11/30/2017 23:59'` is **NOT** a good way to define an end point, it is one full minute short of Dec. 1st. Far better to **stop using between** for date ranges. "Less than December 1 2017" is the most accurate way of defining the cutoff point. So, instead of between, use the style shown in this answer which involves `>=` and `<`
- 'select distinct' is NOT needed when you are doing `group by` in a single query. (The `group by` clause by definition produces rows that are unique so `select distinct` is just a waste of time. The grouping is done before the select cluse too.)
- `FULL JOIN` is very expensive, and not often used. It wasn't required in your existing query because all the data comes from the exact same tables, so there can be no unmatched rows coming from the subqueries.

Comment: Thanku so much for a  detailed explanation.. It is not printing 3rd last column in results. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea why a query you are running does not display the third last column.  Change the column layout perhaps.

Comment: Hi can u please help me with this. I am not understanding why is it happening https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783630/aggregate-functions-on-multiple-tables-not-giving-correct-results?noredirect=1#comment82528638_47783630

Comment: when you add orderdetails you multiply the number of rows. that's why.