# Aggregate functions on multiple tables not giving correct results

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have  following query which works perfectly when join is done on two tables(customers and orders). All calculations are right.

```
   SELECT
         Customers.EmailAddress
         ,COUNT(Orders.OrderID)   AS 'overall NumOrders'
         ,SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount)  AS 'overall TotalOrdered'
           ,COUNT(case when Orders.OrderDate >= '20170101' then Orders.OrderID  end) AS '2017 NumOrders'
        ,SUM(  case when Orders.OrderDate >= '20170101' then Orders.PaymentAmount end) AS '2017 TotalOrdered'
       ,COUNT(case when Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2015 00:00' AND '12/31/2015 23:59' THEN Orders.OrderID   end) AS '2015 NumOrders'
        ,SUM(case when Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2015 00:00' AND '12/31/2015 23:59' then Orders.PaymentAmount end) AS '2015 TotalOrdered'
         FROM Customers
     JOIN Orders ON Customers.Customerid = Orders.Customerid
    WHERE
    Orders.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled','Payment Declined')
    AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2015 00:00' AND getdate()
    GROUP BY 
          Customers.EmailAddress
```

correct Results:

```
Emailaddress|overallnumorders|overalltotalordered|2017numorder|2017totalordered| 2015numorder|2015totalordered
xyz@gmail.com 1                    23.99            0             0                      1               23.99
```

But when i add 3 tables to the above query (customers,orders,orderdetails) I am getting doubled up values

```
SELECT
     Customers.EmailAddress
     ,COUNT(Orders.OrderID)   AS 'overall NumOrders'
     ,SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount)  AS 'overall TotalOrdered'
SUM((OrderDetails.Vendor_Price) * (OrderDetails.Quantity) ) AS TotalCost,
       ,COUNT(case when Orders.OrderDate >= '20170101' then Orders.OrderID  end) AS '2017 NumOrders'
    ,SUM(  case when Orders.OrderDate >= '20170101' then Orders.PaymentAmount end) AS '2017 TotalOrdered'
   ,COUNT(case when Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2015 00:00' AND '12/31/2015 23:59' THEN Orders.OrderID   end) AS '2015 NumOrders'
    ,SUM(case when Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2015 00:00' AND '12/31/2015 23:59' then Orders.PaymentAmount end) AS '2015 TotalOrdered'
     FROM Customers
 JOIN Orders ON Customers.Customerid = Orders.Customerid
JOIN Orderdetails ON Orders.Orderid=Orderdetails.Orderid
WHERE
Orders.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled','Payment Declined')
AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2015 00:00' AND getdate()
GROUP BY 
      Customers.EmailAddress
```

incorrect Results:

```
    Emailaddress|overallnumorders|overalltotalordered|totalcost|2017numorder|2017totalordered| 2015numorder|2015totalordered
 xyz@gmail.com          2           47.98             11.99          0             0                      2               47.98
```

why doing the join on third table is changing calculations? where I want correct results as :

```
Emailaddress|overallnumorders|overalltotalordered|totalcost|2017numorder|2017totalordered| 2015numorder|2015totalordered
    xyz@gmail.com 1                    23.99      11.99      0             0                      1               23.99
```

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: when you add orderdetails there are more rows for each order. That impacts on all the aggregations. Why do you need orderdetails? What column(s) from that table do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add another table you can affect the number of rows and when that happens aggregations will be affected too. To avoid this aggregate the detail table so that there can only be one row per order, then the other aggregations will remain consistent.

```
SELECT
      Customers.EmailAddress
    , COUNT(Orders.OrderID)                                                                                            AS 'overall NumOrders'
    , SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount)                                                                                        AS 'overall TotalOrdered'
    , SUM(od.totalcost) AS totalcost
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Orders.OrderDate >= '20170101' THEN Orders.OrderID END)                                          AS '2017 NumOrders'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.OrderDate >= '20170101' THEN Orders.PaymentAmount END)                                      AS '2017 TotalOrdered'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2015 00:00' AND '12/31/2015 23:59' THEN Orders.OrderID END)     AS '2015 NumOrders'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2015 00:00' AND '12/31/2015 23:59' THEN Orders.PaymentAmount END) AS '2015 TotalOrdered'
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders ON Customers.Customerid = Orders.Customerid
JOIN (
      SELECT
            Orderid
          , SUM((Vendor_Price) * (Quantity)) AS totalcost
      FROM OrderDetails
      GROUP BY
            Orderid
) od ON Orders.Orderid = od.Orderid
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Payment Declined')
AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2015 00:00' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY
      Customers.EmailAddress
```

## EDIT

Please don't use "23:59" as an end point for a date range, that isn't accurate and can lead to incorrect results. There is a vry simple and more accurate alternative which just requires you to stop using "between". Additionally '12/31/2015 23:59' is **NOT** a safe way to specify a date/time value. Use '20160101' which **IS** the safest ate literal format in SQL Server `YYYYMMDD` .

```
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Orders.OrderDate >= '20150101' AND Orders.OrderDate < '20160101' THEN Orders.OrderID END)     AS '2015 NumOrders'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.OrderDate >='20150101' AND Orders.OrderDate < '20160101' THEN Orders.PaymentAmount END) AS '2015 TotalOrdered'
```

Comment: Thank so much for the response. I want to add that all my records are unique by emailaddress. This join is giving me duplicate records for emailaddress.

Comment: Its not I don't like your answer I completely understand your concern as you don't know the whole data and debugging like this is difficult. Only issue in the returning results is all the orders are unique by customer emailaddress and not by orderid. so in the subquery is there any way we can join customers table too to combine the all orders for that particular customer?

Comment: `, SUM(od.totalcost) AS totalcost` should solve the problem